# "Нет доступных вам очередей проверок" - нет причины запрета доступа к очередям проверок

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, очередь-проверок

Получил запрет на очереди проверок, при попытке открыть очереди проверок вылезает сообщение `Нет доступных вам очередей проверок`:

[image: 1]

Никаких объяснений, просто запрет на проверки. А при попытке перейти на страницу очереди проверок, около ссылок появляются такие сообщения `Слишком много ваших правок было отклонено`:

[image: 2]

Возникают вопросы:

1. Про какие-такие правки идёт речь?
2. Какова причина отклонения проверок?
3. Почему я был заблокирован на всех очередях?

Как я понял, должно появляться сообщение с разъяснениями и до какой даты я был заблокирован. Об этом был написан [ответ на Мете](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11114/#11116). Из-за этого возникают ещё вопросы:

4. Почему мне не показало такого сообщения?
5. Заблокирован ли я навсегда?

Подсчитав процент неправильных проверок (вопросы / ответы которые я отметил как "Выглядит нормально", но позже были удалены), я удивился своей блокировке ещё больше.

- 3.3% - Первые вопросы (`12 / 359 * 100`)
- 2.9% - Первые ответы (`1 / 34 * 100`)
- 0% - Запоздалые ответы (`0 / 29 * 100`, я знаю что делить на 0 нельзя, но мы ведь программисты)

В итоге каждые не правильные проверки, не составили даже 4% от общего кол-ва проверок. Судя из сообщения (ответа) из Меты, меня заблокировали только на 7 дней, но всё равно хотелось бы понять причину блокировки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, речь именно про правки, а не про проверки. Обычные предлагаемые правки.

[image]

Скорее всего для данных очередей предполагается, что частым действием будет правка, а если она недоступна, то и в очередь пускать не имеет смысла.

Comment: Хммм, пока что это единственное что имеет смысл, т.к. до этого у меня отменили правку в [другом сообщении](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1483892#comment2659073_1483948). Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: И снова здравствуйте, решил посмотреть сколько же у меня процентов отклонённых правок, в конечном итоге получилось: 26.3%, ну и 73.7% принятых соответственно (`(11 + 17 + 16 + 14 + 13 + 19 + 8) / 133 * 100`), по какому принципу работает запрет? Не совсем понятно, в основном ведь мои правки приняты. Буду очень рад если вы объясните.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, из последних 20 правок отклонено 9, а из последних 10 - 6. Вряд ли там за всё время считается. Точнее не знаю, эта штука автоматическая.